# Drupal 8 Local Set Up

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to import a Drupal 8 site from a git repository.

I am using Acquia Dev Desktop 2 to set it up.

But, I always get this error:

[image]

Do you know what is causing this error?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the error message as text.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your local site's database connection does not have the same settings as the one you're cloning. DevDesktop tries to access the database with with `drupaluser` as the username and no password.

Unless you're using Acquia Cloud and can sync your DB using DevDesktop, I would recommend exporting your remote db from the site you're cloning. Then create a new database in DevDesktop and either import the database using rsync or phpmyadmin, or instruct DD to import it from the dump file.

Then you have to tell Drupal to pick up the new database with the new credentials, so your local settings.php must contain your local database info:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => '<yourDatabaseNameHere>',
  'username' => 'drupaluser',
  'password' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => 33067,
);
```